# My Flutter firebase sign out is clashing with my booking system

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am making a app that does bookings but I get a error about my sign out, this did not happen before I added booking system.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PROVIDER ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6595): The following assertion was thrown:
I/flutter ( 6595): An exception was throw by _MapStream<FirebaseUser, User> listened by
I/flutter ( 6595): StreamProvider<User>, but no `catchError` was provided.
I/flutter ( 6595): 
I/flutter ( 6595): Exception:
I/flutter ( 6595): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 6595): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 6595): Tried calling: uid
```

I know this was answered but i cannot use that code since my bookings page is dependent on the one line of code that the sign out doesn't want.
my auth page code that my bookings needs:

```
//create user object based on firebase user
User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user){

   userId(user.uid);
 //if i comment the above line out my signout works but bookings not
  return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got that error because you are already signed out, then there is no user currently logged in. You need to change the code to the following:

```
User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user){
    userId(user?.uid ?? "no user")
  return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;

}
```